# setenv/clearenv + procfs environ

Tags: linux, procfs, setenv

Is it possible to get relevant information from `/proc/pid/environ` file if process modified its environment? My tests show that `setenv/putenv/clearenv` don't update `environ` file. However, in `bash` its possible to call `unset ENV` and see changes in procfs.

Comment: This author wrote a three (but not four) part explanation of why it doesn't already work.

https://codywu2010.wordpress.com/2014/09/14/procfs-environ-explained-in-depth-1/
https://codywu2010.wordpress.com/2014/09/14/procfs-environ-explained-in-depth-2/
https://codywu2010.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/procfs-environ-explained-in-depth-3/

Comment: I also found some Perl folks trying to figure this out: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=303181

Comment: Ultimately, I believe this is not possible (despite really hoping it is). My guess why you're seeing different behavior in bash is that however you're checking the environment is actually running in a subshell.

Comment: @jtolds I tried my bash example and it didn't worked. So might be that I was indeed mistaken in the first place. Seems like its indeed impossible. You can add this as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`man proc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), under `/proc/[pid]/environ`,

> If, after an execve(2), the process modifies its environment (e.g., by calling functions such as putenv(3) or modifying the environ(7) variable directly), this file will *not* reflect those changes.

So, it doesn't appear to be possible.